# how to access ajax response data inside of data

Tags: ajax

```
0: description: "Highest Intent"intent_id: 1intent_level: "highest"num_of_accounts: 0__proto__: Object1: 
1: {intent_id: 2, intent_level: "high", description: "High Intent", num_of_accounts: 0}
2: {intent_id: 3, intent_level: "medium", description: "Medium Intent", num_of_accounts: 0}
3: {intent_id: 4, intent_level: "low", description: "Low Intent", num_of_accounts: 0}length: 4__proto__: Array(0).
```

Here i need to access intent_level either "high" or "medium" or "low".

axios.get("/some_api/", {
            async: false,
            params: {
                client_id: clientObj.id,
                metric: "intent",
                campaign_id: campaign_id,
                from_date : moment.tz(this.state.intentStartDate, clientObj.timezone_name).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                to_date : moment.tz(this.state.intentEndDate, clientObj.timezone_name).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
            }
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data.metric_data);
            console.log(res.data.metric_data);
            console.log(res.data.campaign_id);
            console.log(res.data.intent_level);
            let intent_obj = new Object();
            res.data.metric_data.forEach(
                function (d) {
                        intent_obj[d.intent_level] = d.num_of_accounts
                        console.log("vvsv"+d.intent_level);
                        in1_level = d.intent_level;
                }

```
        );


        });
```

Comment: Which row data you want to get?

Comment: intent_level of all the rows

Comment: Okay, share you ajax code so I can give you exact code

Comment: sure, i have added

Comment: In which variable your are getting above response : res.data or res.data.metric_data?

Comment: res.data.metric_data

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(intent_obj) after each loop?

Comment: yes, but its giving [object Object]